# PostgreSQL policy to check if email exists in array

Tags: sql, postgresql, policy

*I have a schema similar to that of reddit's so I have changed the table names and columns to make it easier to understand*

I am having issues creating a policy for an update function which involves an array.

I've got 3 tables subreddits, posts and comments which are visually represented as follows.

#### subreddits

| subreddit_id | moderators | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [test@test.com, elonmusk@tsla.com] | ... |
| 2 | [mark@zucc.com] | ... |

#### posts

| subreddit_id | post_id | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 18 | ... |
| 2 | 35 | ... |

#### comments

| id | post_id | comment_text | author | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 18 | 'Hello world' | 81283. | active |
| 2 | 18 | 'comment 2' | 75563 | flagged |
| 3 | 35 | 'comment 123' | 71143 | deleted |

When selecting moderators for the subreddit in which the comment exists, I can run the following query.

```
SELECT moderators FROM subreddit
JOIN posts
 ON subreddit.subreddit_id = posts.subreddit_id
INNER JOIN comments
ON comments.post_id = posts.id
 WHERE comments.id = 1;
```

And the following line returns the subreddit IDs where the current user is a moderator.

```
select subreddit_id from subreddits where 'test@test.com'=ANY(moderators);
```

When a comment is posted by a user on to a post in a particular subreddit, I intend to allow the moderators to edit the comment's status and also the author of the comment to delete the comment (however, deleting doesn't actually delete the comment, but rather changes the status to deleted).

Now, my question is, how do I formulate a policy that only allows updates if the current user who is logged in is either the moderator of the subreddit (has an email that exists in the moderator array) or the author of the comment.

Comment: Unrelated to your question but your first table is not in 1NF, consider normalising it. Remove the column moderators from it and create a new table (subreddit_id, moderator).

Comment: @Zaki oh are you saying that it should instead be such that each moderator would be in one row? I think that solves my problem. Thank you so much